# ADFS with other user registeries than AD

Tags: active-directory, adfs

I would like to configure ADFS to authenticate users and return access-token för SSO from other user sources.

Is it possible to use ADFS for SSO but toward other user registeries than AD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - it only works for AD and for ADAM (LDS).

What you can do is use products like identityserver and Auth0 to handle these user sources and then federate them with ADFS.

Comment: thanks #nzpcmad for your answer. But why you can add other Relying Parites to ADFS? so does it means that you can use ADFS towards other user sources via a Relaying Party that is registered inside ADFS?

Comment: OK - so your question is actually "Can ADFS federate with other IDP that do not use AD". Yes.

Answer (score 2):

One minor correction to nzpcmad's answer. In ADFS 2016, ADFS can login users from any 3rd party LDAP repository including virtual directories that can wrap a SQL DB and expose as LDAP. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/configure-ad-fs-to-authenticate-users-stored-in-ldap-directories